# svg.getScreenCTM is not a function?

Tags: svg

i need to draw textbox dynamically on svg but i am getting error as getScreenCTM is not a function so what can be the solution

```
var mousedownonelement = false;

window.getlocalmousecoord = function (svg, evt) {

    editor.x = evt.clientX;
    editor.y = evt.clientY;
    var localpoint = editor.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    localpoint.x = Math.round(localpoint.x);
    localpoint.y = Math.round(localpoint.y);
    return localpoint;
};

window.createtext = function (localpoint, svg) {
    var myforeign = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject')
    var textdiv = document.createElement("div");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("type the text.....");
    textdiv.appendChild(textnode);
    textdiv.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
    textdiv.setAttribute("width", "auto");
    myforeign.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    myforeign.setAttribute("height", "100%");
    myforeign.classList.add("foreign"); 
    textdiv.classList.add("insideforeign"); 
    textdiv.addEventListener("mousedown", elementMousedown, false);
    myforeign.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate(" + localpoint.x + " " + localpoint.y + ")");
    svg.appendChild(myforeign);
    myforeign.appendChild(textdiv);

};

function elementMousedown(evt) {
    alert("elementMousedown");
    mousedownonelement = true;
}
```

since it is mouse events it works only on desktop so what can be the solution for ipad touch event will this logic works

```
$('#calloutbox').click(function (evt) {
    var svg = document.getElementById('canvas');
    alert(svg);
    var localpoint = getlocalmousecoord(svg, evt);
    if (!mousedownonelement) {
        createtext(localpoint, svg);
    } else {
        mousedownonelement = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What element has the id 'canvas' ?

Comment: <div id="canvas"></div> div element

Comment: And there you have it, div is not an SVG element (strictly speaking an SVG element that supports the SVGLocatable interface) so you can't call getScreenCTM on it.

Comment: then how can  i fix this

Comment: Call getScreenCTM on an svg element. I don't really know what your code is trying to do so it's hard to comment further.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue with **D3 v5**

Changed
**From**

```js
.on("mouseover",function(d) { tip.show(d)})
```

**To**

```js
.on("mouseover",function(d) { tip.show(d, this)})
```

`d3Tip` automatically resolves the value of `i` No need to pass it explicitely.
For more details refer this [thread](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/issues/231)

Answer (score 2):

If someone's using version D3 V5+, here's what you can do. Referenced from this post in GitHub https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/issues/231#issuecomment-459758872

```
.on('mouseover', (data, index, element) => tip.show(data, element[index]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser may not support `getScreenCTM()` by default. See [here](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/50789) for a way to enable it locally, and [here](http://www.codedread.com/dragtest2.svg) for an example of in use locally.

As for touch events, the results you receive from your evt callback are a little different. The logic is fine, but the coordinates are not stored in `evt.clientX/Y`, they're stored in `evt.touches[0].clientX/Y`.

Comment: He's adding a handler to a html element and calling getScreenCTM on it. That's not going to work even on UAs that do support getScreenCTM. This answer rather misses that point.